# OpenCV structuring element ellipse and cross

Tags: opencv

Can anyone tell me what does it mean that a kernel has an elliptic or cross shape?
Can anyone give me an example how that kind of kernel should look?

On the lines when you use MORPH_ELLIPSE and MORPH_CROSS in OpenCV.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/mathematical-morphology/.

Comment: Thanks :D I thought it looked like this but I got confused when I read in literature about "Robert's CROSS operator" for detecting edges.... I thought the structuring element looked like the mask of that operator :)